# I've been using this docstring syntax for 2 years now, what's it called, who specifies it, and is it "ok" to use it?

Tags: python, syntax, docstring

I've been using this weird syntax for a long time now, and am getting quite good at it.
It's like taking the good part about java, and having that in Python. It's awesome, I like it, my IDE even caught some bugs because of the annotations.

I don't know however who specified this syntax, how official it is, and I don't know the exact rules for it.

Admittedly, I'm using PyCharm, but I don't know if this would work in other IDEs, or if it's just PyCharm syntax - I don'w want to think it is, and I'd like to use a docstring syntax that works for other tools as well.

Moreover, I see the amazon people using this kind of syntax in their python library boto:
https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/beanstalk/layer1.py#L83

Here's an example of the syntax.

```
def asdf(name, descriptions, weird_dict):
    """
    :type weird_dict: dict[tuple[str|None],list[dict[int,str]|MyClass]]
    :param weird_dict: description description

    :type name: str
    :param list[str] descriptions: Description and type annotation

    :param str name: Here I declared the "suggested" type, and can also describe the param

    :return:  Here I just describe what's returned
    :rtype: int
    """
```

Please tell me, if anyone knows, what is the name of this syntax, who specifies it, and how I can find more info about it, because I tried a few times and just ended up on the PyCharm site.

Answer (score 2):

That is [reStructuredText Docstring Format](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/) as specified by PEP 287

PyCharm also has the following docstring formats under the [Python Integrated Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python-integrated-tools.html) settings

- Plain
- [Epytext](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/)
- [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)
- [NumPy](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html)
- [Google](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html)