# What style does PyCharm / IntelliJ use for Python docstrings?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, docstring

I'm trying to understand the "solution ecosystem" with respect to creating docstrings, and then generating some nice reference documentation with PyCharm/IntelliJ.

I'm used to the Google style docstrings, and am confused by PyCharm's default docstring skeleton format/style however:

```
"""
:param <paramname>: blah blah
:return None
"""
```

What style is this and what reference doc generators does it work with?  Is there a style guide somewhere?

Comment: That is the [reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081675/ive-been-using-this-docstring-syntax-for-2-years-now-whats-it-called-who-spe) docstring style. That style is specified by [PEP 287](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) style doc strings.

Python has some strong opinions about doc strings, see [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Here is a full description of all of the doc string types in Python: [What is the standard Python docstring format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format)